# how to setup angular routing for multi page application?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I am creating a web application (multi page) using angular 6 and want to setup routes module for different views. So far i could see examples which shows components are rendered in the same page (index page) using router-outlet element and routerLink attribute in a tag.

In multi page application how to set up the routes which can redirect to different page and load the angular components ?

Comment: if i'm understand your question. read Angular is full featured SPA framework,with the help of which single page application is created. In the SPA whole page is not reloaded every time,every time view will be change.  So when you load the application for the first time not all the pages from the server will be rendered..Its only index.html that loads when you load the application.Since only single page is loaded it is called as SPA

Comment: Thanks @abhishek. I understand how the SPA works in general. What i want to know if am using angular for multi page application. how the router should work ? meaning if user click on a link in index.html which redirects to different page say contact.html how to load angular components in there. Should i have app-root tag in the contact.html as well ? but that would load root component again.

Comment: you can go through this link for [angular routing](https://angular.io/guide/router). It has all the answers you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, Angular is a Single Page Application Framework. There is ne need to have another page like contact.html. You generate a component called contacs or so and in your router you simply reference the component with the path youd like, for example "/contacts".
I've done a quick research and found that there should be no need to have multiple static html files in angular. Maybe you should reconsider your Framework choice and use a Framework which is meant to be used with multiple html files! 
Good Luck